# what would happen to deleted answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

What would happen if delete your own answer posted before? Can people see the answer only with a `deleted` tag under the response or the answer would be disappear totally?

What about down votes? Does day return back? for example if your answer down voted by 2 people and then you delete the answer, does your score increment by 2?

Comment: Yes, users with 10k+ rep can see your deleted answer. Yes, the rep lost on downvotes, is rewarded back on you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers